# Can a Static Method/Property be saved as a PowerShell Object?

Tags: powershell

Is it possible to do something like `$test = [string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace` and then check whether a `$var` is Null/Empty/WhiteSpace with `$test`? I'm not just asking specific to that static method, but in general I've seen folks assign an object to a variable and then take action on the object without typing its full name and I'm wondering if a similar syntax is possible with a string method or any method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can assign .NET methods to variables!

PowerShell returns a [`PSMethod`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.psmethod) object when you access a method without a parameter list ( the `(...)` part after the method name).
This is really just a thin wrapper around the underlying .NET method, and it conveniently allows you to invoke it, using [`Invoke()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.psmethod.invoke):

```
PS ~> $test = [string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace
PS ~> $test.Invoke("")
True
PS ~> $test.Invoke("   ")
True
PS ~> $test.Invoke("!")
False
```

Comment: Awesome - I'm sure I can just test this pretty quickly, but can you store additional logic in the variable? Obviously too complex and the variable would be its own mini-function, but what about something like `$exists = !([string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace)`?

Comment: No, but you can wrap the call in a scriptblock like so: `$exists = {-not [string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($args[0])}; & $exists "nonempty"`.

Comment: Actually I guess that would potentially make sense if `.Invoke()` would work the same as `Invoke-CMD` or `Invoke-Expression` - so I wonder if there is an overhead difference loading something into a variable or string vs. it being formally defined as a function. Is there a limit to how much you can Invoke using `.Invoke()`? If `$a =' .Invoke'`, `$b = [string]::IsNullOrEmpty`, `$c = [string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace`, and `$d = 'ToUpper()' - what is `$b$a($c$a('test'.$d))`?

Comment: @immobile2 Whether it "makes sense" depends entirely on what you're trying to achieve, and it's not at all clear to me what's you're actually trying to do here :)

Comment: Well that isn't the best example, but I'll come up with another in the morning!

Answer (score 2):

To complement [Mathias R. Jessen's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69321161/45375):

If it's acceptable to specify the *type* every time and only store the *method name*  (or *property* name) in a variable, you can use normal invocation syntax:

```sh
$n = 'IsNullOrWhiteSpace'

[string]::$n('foo') # -> $false
[string]::$n('') # -> $true
```

The same technique works with *instance* members:

```sh
# Method
$n = 'ToUpper'
'foo'.$n() # -> 'FOO'

# Property
$n = 'Length'
'foo'.$n # -> 3
```

The above techniques also work with *expressions* (enclosed in `(...)`):

```sh
# Method
'foo'.('To' + 'Upper')() # -> 'FOO'

# Property
'foo'.('Le' + 'ngth') # -> 3
```